# Doctrine EntityManager Error

Tags: php, doctrine

i have this file: config.php
with this code:

```html
   
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//doctrine
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array(
 __DIR__ . "/entidades"
);

$isDevMode = false;
//configuracion de coneccion
$dbParams = array(
 'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
 'host' => '127.0.0.1',
 'user' => 'root',
 'password' => '',
 'dbname' => 'ClinicaDental'
  
);

$configDoctrine = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $configDoctrine);
```

and this file nuevo_archivo.php

```
$resultados = $entityManager->getRepository('\entidades\usuarios')->findAll();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($resultados);
        echo "</pre>";
```

the error I receive when you run the nuevo archivo.php file is this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class '\entidades\usuarios' does not exist' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ClinicaDental/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:96 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ClinicaDental/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php(41): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::nonExistingClass('\\entidades\\usua...') #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ClinicaDental/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(281): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getParentClasses('\\entidades\\usua...') #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ClinicaDental/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(311): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getPare in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ClinicaDental/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 96
```

My folder is where saved my entities is "entities"
Looking seems to me entities in another folder, from where I tell him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried without the intiial `\` ?

You can try this code:

```
var_dump(get_declared_classes());
```

and check if you can see your `usuarios` class.

---

You can also try to use a:

```
use entidates\usuarios;

$entityManager->getRepository('usuarios')->findAll();
```